# Getting all of the FieldB Values where FieldA is duplicated in MySql

Tags: mysql

Given a table with two fields say `FirstName` and `LastName1` can I extract via a Mysql query an output which has one row for each FirstName with a concatenated list of `LastNames`:

```
 - Bob  |  Smith
 - Bob  |  Jones
 - Bob  |  Adams
 - Jack |  Abrams
 - Jack | Andrews
```

Would become:

```
- Bob  | Smith;Jones;Adams
- Jack | Abrams;Andrews
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT

```
select FirstName, GROUP_CONCAT(LastName1 separator ';') lastnames
from your_table
group by FirstName;
```